# Using jQuery append function to swap elements with fade transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to use jquery fadeTo method as a transition between append method requests of a particular `li` tag, my script swaps `li`'s within div id "placeholder" upon mouseclick of a div called by id "viewMore" however I can't seem to get the right ordering of functions. What is happening is when the user clicks "View More" the the `li` gets swapped instantly before the fade occurs, afterward the fade out occurs on the new `li` then the new `li` fades back in. Can someone please help me adjust the hierarchy of methods. Below is my script that loops through an `ul` injected with JSON data. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: `setTimeOut` was the solution to this, a great method. - 1/11/14 1:24PM

```
    $.getJSON('assets/data/data_001.json', function(data)
    {

      $("#placeholder").html("");
      var ul = $('<ul></ul>');
      $('#placeholder').append(ul);
      var load = $("#imgLd");
      var load2 = $("#titleLd");
      var load3 = $("#priceLd");
      var load4 = $("#descriptionLd");
      var load5 = $("#cartLd");
      $('#cartLd').fadeTo(0,0);

      for(var i in data.items)
      {

        var li = $('<li class=listItem></li>');
        ul.append(li);
        var img = $('<img>');
        img.attr("src", "assets/images/items/" + data.items[i].thumb + ".jpg");
        var title = $("<h3 class=itemTextTitle>" + data.items[i].title + "</h3>");
        var price = $("<h4 class=itemTextPrice>" + data.items[i].price + "</h4>");
        var viewMore = $("<div class=viewMore price=" + data.items[i].price + ">View More</div>");
        viewMore.mousedown((function(x)
        { 

          return function()
          {
            $('#intro').fadeTo(500,0);
            $('#cartLd').delay(750).fadeTo(500,1);
            $('#introBg').delay(500).fadeTo(500,0);
            load.html("<img src=assets/images/items/" + data.items[x].thumb2 + ".jpg>");
            load2.html("<h3 class=itemTextTitle2>" + data.items[x].title + "</h3>");
            load3.html("<h4 class=itemTextPrice>" + data.items[x].price + "</h4>");
            load4.html("<ul class=itemTextDescription>" + 
                            "<li class=itemTextDescription2>" + data.items[x].description.one + "</li>" +
                            "<li>" + data.items[x].description.two + "</li><li>" + data.items[x].description.three + "</li>" + 
                            "</ul>");
            load5.html("<a class=itemCartClick href=#>Add to Cart</a>");
            var priceOutput =" + data.items[x].price + ";

            $('.itemCartClick').on('click', function(){
                alert(JSON.stringify(data.items[x].price));
            });
          }
        })(i));
        li.append(img).append(title).append(price).append(viewMore).append(viewMore);
      }
    });
```

Here is my markup if it helps:

```
        <h3 id="titleLd"></h3>
        <h4 id="descriptionLd"></h4>
        <a id="cartLd" href="#">Add to Cart</a>
        <div id="hero">
        <div id="hero_lft">
            <h3 id="imgLd"></h3>
        </div>
        <div id="hero_rt">
            <h3 id="priceLd"></h3>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div id="intro">
            <h2 class="introText"><div id="logo"></div></h2>
            <h3 class="introText2">Hover over an item to view</h3>
        </div>
        <div id="introBg"></div>
        <div id="placeholder"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use callback functions like this :

```
$('#intro').fadeTo(500,0, function() {
    // do stuff when fade out is complete
    // typically ends with a fadeIn (or fadeTo(delay,1) on 
    // the element you hid previously
});
```

You can also write a function and pass its name as third parameter for fadeTo (see [fadeTo doc](http://api.jquery.com/fadeto/)), or use the .queue() function (see [this tutorial](http://learn.jquery.com/effects/uses-of-queue-and-dequeue/), a little bit more tricky).

Think about using fadeOut(delay) instead of fadeTo(delay, 0) too, and use [.on("click")](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of mousedown().

A JSFiddle would be helpful (I don't fully understand your use case) but in order to clarify all this you should manage the viewMore.on('click') outside of your 'for' loop - it means storing on each li its index in your data.items array, e.g with a data attribute or the jQuery data() function (in your 'for' loop : li.data('itemIndex',i); ) :

```
for(var i in data.items) { // construct the list }

$('.viewMore').on('click', '#placeholder', function() {
    var i = $(this).data('itemIndex');
    $('#intro').fadeOut(500, function() {
        // modify your DOM using your JSON array (data.items[i])
        $(this).fadeIn(500);
    });
});
```

And don't be affraid to nest functions in jQuery, callbacks and events firing them are the whole point of jQuery !

Good luck

Comment: So your saying wrap the child function in another, new function? I'm sure that will work but it seems like I have a mess of too many functions. I'm just a little lost in my nested functions, this is actually a project I started a year ago and am just now picking back up on it. Since I took a break I've been working with Java and jQuery has become foreign to me. Is there a neat way to rewrite my code to shrink down on functions or do I need 3 nested? Thanks.

Comment: actually, it was pretty foreign to me a year ago too lol. I basically just hacked away and got something that works pretty good but now I have no idea how to manipulate the hierarchy; can you provide an example of how to rewrite my nested functions? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Bammmmmmm:

```
      for(var i in data.items)
      {

        var li = $('<li class=listItem></li>');
        ul.append(li);
        var img = $('<img>');
        img.attr("src", "assets/images/items/" + data.items[i].thumb + ".jpg");
        var title = $("<h3 class=itemTextTitle>" + data.items[i].title + "</h3>");
        var price = $("<h4 class=itemTextPrice>" + data.items[i].price + "</h4>");
        var viewMore = $("<div class=viewMore price=" + data.items[i].price + ">View More</div>");
        viewMore.on('click', function(x)
        { 

          return function()
          {
            $('#intro').fadeTo(500,1);
            $('#cartLd').fadeTo(500,1);
            $('#introBg').fadeTo(500,1);

            setTimeout(function () {
                load.html("<img src=assets/images/items/" + data.items[x].thumb2 + ".jpg>");
                load2.html("<h3 class=itemTextTitle2>" + data.items[x].title + "</h3>");
                load3.html("<h4 class=itemTextPrice>" + data.items[x].price + "</h4>");
                load4.html("<ul class=itemTextDescription>" + 
                                "<li>" + data.items[x].description.one + "</li>" +
                                "<li>" + data.items[x].description.two + "</li>" +
                                "<li>" + data.items[x].description.three + "</li>" + 
                                "</ul>");
                load5.html("<a class=itemCartClick href=#>Add to Cart</a>");
                var priceOutput =" + data.items[x].price + ";

                $('.itemCartClick').on('click', function(){
                    alert(JSON.stringify(data.items[x].price));
                });
            }, 600);

            $('#intro').fadeTo(500,0);
            $('#introBg').fadeTo(500,0);

          }
        }(i));
        li.append(img).append(title).append(price).append(viewMore).append(viewMore);
      }
```

My favorite jQuery function, `setTimeOut`, I forgot about it and just remembered it. It fixed the problem. @Flo Flo, thanks for pointing out .on instead of JS's onmouseclick. I swapped it out.